# Headers on appendix

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I can't find the solution to this problem. I did google it and nothing came out. My project has 3 chapters and the appendix, but as far as I used `\chapter*{Ap\'endice}` and so, the appendix page headers are the same as third's chapter (I assume this is why).

I want to have something like "Number (space) Apéndice" on even pages and "Apéndice (space) Number" on odd pages.

I already tried the `afterpage` package. `\afterpage{\lhead{Ap\'endice}` or `\afterpage{\rhead{Ap\'endice}}` modifies every page after that and since this is the `book` class with different even and odd pages headers, `\lhead` on even pages replaces the page number and the same with `\rhead` on odd pages. Is there any way to solve this out?

I would really appreciate your help.

I'm using fancyhdr package, I'm sorry I didn't made that clear before. Here's my code. As you would see when compile, page 4 (Appendix) header is Capítulo 1 instead of Ap\'endice.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy} 

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Cap\'itulo 1}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Ap\'endice}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ap\'endice: Teor\'ia de Grupos}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\lipsum[2]. \newpage
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a compilable document in order to show the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [fancyhdr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package and the command `\fancyhead`

```
\chapter*{Ap\'endice}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{Ap\'endice}
\fancyhead[LO]{Ap\'endice}
```

**Edit:** To clarify, you have to set a propper page style for this to work. Add

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

to the beginning of your document.

Alternatively, you can simply declare the chapter to be an appendix by stating

```
\appendix
\chapter{Name of the appendix}
```

Note that here I have used the standard `\chapter` command, not the `\chapter*` command. This will produce slightly different results, however, it might be a more robust (and in my opinion better) solution.